# VBA to get selected shape name in Combobox

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA. i have few shapes in a worksheet.
I want to get the name of shape to appear in combobox and character name in another Combobox, when any particular shape is selected. so i can rename that shape and link to particular excel column.

i have tried following.

```
With Selection
    ActiveSheet.ComboBox1.Value = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name
End with
```

Not sure where to assign above code.

I tried assigning above code to a shape with .onaction as macro, it work but a marco assiged shape cannot be edited further(For design purpose).

Also It would be great if i can delete selected shape.

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/10/22/activeshape-with-vba

Comment: Are you talking about simple shapes as Rectangle ones? I mean, not controls...

Comment: yes, These are flowchart shapes @FaneDuru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your code for any shape and you can change the code whenever you want, but assigning a macro, she shape will will not be selected when clicked... It becomes a kind of control.

Excepting the case when you force it to select:

```
Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name
shW.ComboBox1.value.Shapes(Application.Caller).Select
```

You can change the code from right click context (on the chart bottom side) and choose 'Assign Macro... -> Edit'.

You can find the selected shape using the next code:

```
Sub testSelectedShape()
   Dim shW As Worksheet, sh As Object, selSh As Object
   Set shW = ActiveSheet
   If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then
      Set selSh = Selection
      Set sh = shW.Shapes(selSh.Name)
      Debug.Print selSh.Name
      shW.ComboBox1.value = selSh.Name
  End If
End Sub
```

You can delete it simple using `sh.Delete`...

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. but i have dynamic shapes added and removed in label design with add shape button. and for every shape its not possible use above codes unless shapes are fixed and not dynamic. Can we trigger above code with worksheet shape selection change event ? any workaround ?

Comment: Probably yes, but now I am driving. I will be back home after 7, 8 hours...

Comment: Ok,. will wait for your response. have a safe drive.

Comment: Just tested your starting two lines of code. which helped me to manage it. but your starting second line of code comes with error "object required". solved it by.  ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Select
ActiveSheet.ComboBox1.Value = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name          
 i shall assign this line of macro for every Shapes.AddShape with .onkey. = "MacroName"

Comment: @HeavyLoad Collection: Glad to hear you solved your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your time and support.